# Ассемблерный код и многопоточность

Tags: ассемблер, c, многопоточность, unix

Всем добрых суток!
Дан бинарник библиотеки неких вычислительных функций, написанных на асемблере, исходников нет, как следствие, глубокого понимания внутренностей данных функций тоже нет.
Есть следующий теоретический вопрос : есть ли возможность безопасного использования данных функций в многопоточном приложении? Понимаю, что можно "ограничить" все вызовы из данной библиотеки мьютексами, однако нет уверенности, что они не станут конфликтовать с другими функциями приложения, например с malloc(). Разрешите мои сомнения плиз.

Comment: @margosh, я не думаю, что вычислительные функции могут конфликтовать с malloc (или чем-то подобным). Использование мьютексов выглядит разумной мерой безопасности. Только вот надо посмотреть, нет ли в библиотеке неких "парных" вызовов (типа open/close). В подобном случае возможно придется "лочить" всю цепочку.

Вряд ли стоит изощряться и вытаскивать эти вычисления в отдельный процесс (быстро работать точно не будет).

Comment: @avp, да, отдельным процессом в данном случае - не пойдет. Посмотреть что внутри не могу, - кроме бинарника ничего нет. Я так себе представляю, что большая часть ассемблерного кода сводится к работе с регистрами, и здесь конфликтов с небиблиотечными функцими быть не должно, но может ли данный код транслироваться в некий системный вызов, не расчитанный на многопоточное использование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае, такая библиотека может Вам стоить бессонных ночей, потраченных на отладку. Не рекомендую к использованию. Если я вообще что-либо пониманию, то тут даже критические секции толком не помогут. Зависит от того создается ли отдельная копия библиотеки на каждый поток. Я лично уверен, что нет. А раз так, то какая-нибудь хитрая ф-ция, модифицирующая внутренние переменные библиотеки и завязанная на их значения, вызванная несколько раз из разных потоков, полностью нарушит логику работы библиотеки.

Comment: Золотые слова. Хочу еще напомнит старую мудрость грибников: Не знаешь гриб - не бери.

Comment: @mikillskegg, в тему =)

Answer (score 0):

> Есть следующий теоретический вопрос :
> есть ли возможность безопасного
> использования данных функций в
> многопоточном приложении?

Вероятность, конечно, есть. Но боюсь, они меньше 100%

Comment: подозреваю, что так... хотелось узнать мнения.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду, чтобы к некоторым секциям приложению не было одновременного, параллельного доступа, то можете использовать такой инструмент, как **[критичные секции](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx)**. Критические секции - это объекты, используемые для блокировки доступа всех нитей (threads) приложения, кроме одной, к некоторым важным данным в один момент времени.  Они обезопасят программу от одновременного доступа к некоторым её секциям кода. Инструмент предельно прост в использовании.

См. **[EnterCriticalSection Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608(v=vs.85).aspx)**

Comment: Идея правильная, но вопрос не об этом. Кроме того, видел тег "unix"?

Comment: @mikillskegg, ах да, точно, Unix же....что-то, как увидел метку "Assembler", так сразу почему-то подумал, что Windows. В таком случае, прошу прощения за ошибку...

Comment: @mikillskegg Ну критические секции везде есть. Вызовы другие. Вопрос только, где их ставить. Если на каждый вызов функции (а они вычислительные) -- то будет правильно, но не быстро. А иначе -- как получится.

Comment: @alexz, проблема не только в быстродействии,а в первую очередь в том, что неизвестно какие куски кода нужно лочить дополнительно, так как неизвестно что используется внутри библиотеки, пример в конце вопроса есть.

Comment: @margosh Или я чего-то не понял, или... Если этот компот будет ещё и с malloc конфликтовать, то уже никакие мьютексы не помогут. То, что написал выше я -- это по сути однопоточная работа, ни в коем случае два потока не могут одновременно вызвать функцию из библиотеки.

Comment: @alexlz, я имею ввиду, что не представляю, есть ли в библиотеке нечто, что могло бы конфликтовать с функциями не из этой библиотеки, malloc() - это просто для примера, это ведь не единственная функция, которая стала потокобезопасной путем добавления в ее код мьютексов. Насчет одновременного вызова библиотечных функций - согласна, нельзя вызывать.